# mod_rewrite reveals re written URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new to URL rewrites so I'm just getting the hang of it. The problem I have is that my rule works and pulls the correct page but after the page loads, it displays the rewritten URL instead of the trailing slashes one in the address bar.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule   ^(.+)/(.+)/([0-9]+)$  ^testing.php?do=$1&see=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

So instead of seeing http://www.example.com/walk/cars/9843928 in the address bar, I see http://www.example.com/testing.php?do=walk&see=cars&id=9843928

Hoe can I get this to work correctly and keep the trailing slashes URL in the bar?

Comment: Is this the only rule in your .htaccess? If not post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target URL shouldn't start with `^`.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ testing.php?do=$1&see=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This keeps the trailing slashes URL but the CSS and JavaScript aren't being added to my HTML. Do I have to re-write the paths to files too?

Comment: Generally the best way to ensure that works wherever you place your files is to add a check that doesn't rewrite the URL if the speficied file/folder actually exists. Before the `RewriteRule` line, add: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d` each on their own line.

Comment: For css, js, images make sure to use absolute paths i.e. starting with `http://` OR `/`

Comment: That didn't work. Again, I have the slashes URL but no CSS or scripts. How does the URL rewrite affect the paths to files? I have them all in an include so it's easy to just change the paths if this doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: It's not enough to say `That didn't work`. You need to write clearly what is not working? Are you still getting `/testing.php?do=...` URL in browser OR css, js etc not loading?

Comment: CSS and JS wasn't loading but I got it working with absolute paths. Much appreciated guys